# AS3: Using mask vs Cropped images

Tags: actionscript-3

there are spritesheets of tiles for a new game I'm developing. I'm planning to use them with mask layers. I mean for example there is 30 different tiles on each spritesheets, to use each one I'm planning to change spritesheet's x and y, so mask will show only the wanted tile.
But the problem is, it may force cpu.

For example if there are 30 tiles on the screen and if each spritesheets has 30 different tiles, that makes 900 tiles if I use mask layer instead of cropping each tiles.

**So the problem is** , If I use mask layer, does it effect the cpu in a bad way, or does only the part under the mask is calculated on cpu?

I hope I could define the problem clearly.

Thank you

-Ozan

Comment: Why don't you use the Starling framework? It is really not difficult to learn, you can get the best performance by using the GPU, and many of these texture problems are solved for you.

Comment: The drawing tools provided via bitmapdata give you the option to copy a section of a spritesheet across onto a new bitmap. This process does not use masking. For sprite-based graphics I would highly recommend Starling, which gives you tools to further simplify working with sprite sheets via textures and texture atlases.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I'll check Starling then. :)

Comment: Well I've checked it and it says Starling uses stage3d. Which is not supported by many flash game websites. So I cannot use Starling.

Answer (score 1):

Starling is a whole new field, as it's using Stage3D. This means you have to rethink your development flow - everything must be as textures and so there are a lot of limitations - you cannot simply design a button in your Flash IDE, give it a name and use it. I'm not saying it's bad, no, I just say you have to you it wise and if you don't have any experience with it - it will take time to learn.

I think you are doing some calculations wrong. You say *For example if there are 30 tiles on the screen and if each spritesheets has 30 different tiles, that makes 900 tiles*, which means you have **30 spritesheets** with **30 tiles on each**. This is a lot of tiles for your game, are you sure? :)

Anyways, the common approach is to use each tile of the spritesheet as an individual one. That's why it's called spritesheet. And the meaning of this is very simple - the memory it will use. Imagine you have 100 tiles in one spritesheet (for easier calculations), and this spritesheet is 1mb. If you splice it in smaller chunks (100 of them), the size of it will be close to 1mb also. So if you do this and delete the original source, the RAM that will be taken because of those bitmaps will be close to the original.

Then you want to use a single tile (or let's say your map is just "water" and you use only one tile). You instantiate many instances of the very same class, and because you use only one kind, the memory that will be taken in order to be displayed is 1/100 of the original 1mb.

What I mean is that the worst case scenario would be to use the total 100 of them at the same time, and this will take 1mb of memory (I'm talking for the images only). Every time you use less, the memory will decrease.

The approach of having a mask is worse, because even if you use a single tile, it will put all of the original spritesheet into memory. Single tile - 1mb. **And** it will also draw a mask object (Sprite) and will also need to precalculate that mask and remove the outer part of the Bitmap. This is more memory, more CPU calculations, and more graphic rendering (as it will draw the cropped Bitmap every time you instantiate).

I think this will give you an idea why it's used that way! :) If you have some fancy regions and that's the reason you want to use masking instead, then use some spritesheet packager program. It will provide you with a data file describing the regions of the spritesheet that are used, and so with a single class (there are many for that) it will parse your initial Bitmap, create Bitmap children for each chunk and destroy the original. And the coordinates won't matter.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Yeah, that's totally what I've asked! Thank you very much. By the way I didn't miscalculate, as you say if I use mask and use whole spritesheet for each individual tile, that makes 900 tiles(30x30) in total :D So that's why I asked if it calculates the whole spritesheet or only the masked part. Anyways thank you very much again, you totally answered what I need. :)